# Why is react looking for ~/Documents/My Pictures?

Tags: reactjs

I am building an app in react.

For some reason, when I compile, react is looking for something in 'My Pictures'. I had it up and running fine, but I ran the following:

```
npm install react-chartjs-2
```

When I did, I got a couple warnings so I then ran:

```
npm audit fix
```

Nothing was actually fixed...

Now, when I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\bjrut\Documents\My Pictures'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\bjrut\\Documents\\My Pictures'
}
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bjrut\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-06T17_10_45_668Z-debug.log
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

The debug file reads:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.17.6
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~prestart: frontend@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: frontend@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\bjrut\Documents\projects\covid-project\frontend\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\bjrut\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\bjrut\bin;C:\Python39\Scripts;C:\Python39;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Users\bjrut\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\bjrut\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\bjrut\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\bjrut\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.1\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\bjrut\Documents\projects\covid-project\frontend
10 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
13 verbose stack     at Process.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:131:17)
14 verbose pkgid frontend@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\bjrut\Documents\projects\covid-project\frontend
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.17.6
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What gives??? Nowhere in my source am I referencing any images stored in 'My Pictures'. In fact, there aren't even any 'pictures'. I tried uninstalling react-chartjs-3, but the error persists. As well, I walked through the entire start.js script with the debugger, and no errors. The error happens at compile time.

I'm at a loss. I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Noticing this error as well, and it seems very recent.

Comment: Yes and no... Yes I fixed it. It turned out that I was not proerly importing a lib; however, the question still stans: Why is node or react looking for 'My Pictures'? My Pictures is not even a directory! It's a junction! It's a NTFS pointer is all. I find it strange. is it that node is looking for the package? I know that node drills down a few levels when looking for node_modules, but I don't ever recall reading that it's a recursive search, which it would have to be if it's reaching ~/documents/my\ pictures.